# apex:param not passing parameter to controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, list, apex-param

In my code the parameter in an apex:param does not get passed on to the controller. Here is the code for Visualforce:

```
<apex:Outputpanel>
<apex:variable value="{!1}" var="row"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!list}" var="item">
        <apex:commandLink value="Action" action="{!performAction}">
             <apex:param value="{!row-1}" assignTo="{!pos}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
        <apex:variable value="{!row+1}" var="row"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:Outputpanel>
```

Controller:

```
public Integer pos {get; set;}


public PageReference performAction() {

    if (list[pos] != null){
        delete list[pos];   
    }
    list.remove(pos);

    return null;
}
```

So what is wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you may be attempting to modify the displayed contents, of some collection, on your visualforce page. Am I right? If so, I can expand on this comment in an answer. Also, if I'm right, this is an example of an X-Y problem (where you ask about how to fix your chosen solution instead of asking for help in achieving your overall goal), and I'd suggest using an `<apex:actionSupport>` along with `rerender` to accomplish a partial page refresh instead of specifying the `action` attribute in your `<apex:commandLink>`.

Answer (score 2):

Though optional you have to put in a name attribute for the apex:param.

Update:

A similar question was answered on why param needs a name attribute. Param gets passed as a key value pair to the controller, you have to specify name for the key value pair to be generated.

[<apex:param> assignTo attribute not setting value to contoller variable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18988/apexparam-assignto-attribute-not-setting-value-to-contoller-variable)

```
         <apex:param value="{!row-1}" assignTo="{!pos}" name="pos"/>
```

Comment: @DanielBallinger the op is using commandlink which as per the idea should work without re-render attribute? I put in a name attribute and tested, the value gets passed to teh controller

Comment: Ah right. Missed that bit.